# array_multisort Converts string index into an integer index

Tags: php, arrays, type-conversion, array-multisort

I have two arrays:

```
 $info = array();
 $submitted = array();
```

I declared an assignment below:

```
 $info['idnumber'] = 10066;
 $submitted[$info['idnumber']] = 'Wow';

 array_multisort($submitted);
```

After doing so, displayed `$submitted` array.

```
 foreach($submitted as $key => $row){
      echo $key;
 }
```

Why does it display `0` instead of `10066`? I tried tweaking my code to:

```
$info['idnumber'] = 10066;
$submitted[(string)$info['idnumber']] = 'Wow';
```

or

```
$info['idnumber'] = 10066;
$submitted[strval($info['idnumber'])] = 'Wow';
```

Still it displays `0`. What shall I do to display `10066` as the index of the `$submitted` array?

**Update:**

I found out it's a known bug of [array_multisort](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=21788), but still it has no solutions. Any idea how to fix ]it?

Comment: What is $printed in your code? I don't see any declarations.

Comment: Sorry, It's only a typo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you pointed out it is a known behaviour.

The solution was proposed in the discussion

> For the moment I'm going to say prefix all your array keys with an extra 0 (or any non-numeric) to force their casting as strings.

When you try to cast integer into string like this:

```
(string)$info['idnumber']
```

you still get the integer, because you have a valid number as a string.

So you need to have a string as with some prefix. Prefix can be a 0 or any other non-numeric character. like an i

```
$info['idnumber'] = '010066';
```

Or

```
$info['idnumber'] = 'i00066';
```

This will return the exact index.